# How can i increase speed of audio file using winmm.dll in Window Application

Tags: c#, winforms, audio

I created one user defined player in which i use winmm.dll to play/pause/stop, etc. now i need to play file using some speed i.e 1x,2x,3x,etc

i use below function which sends some command

```
        cmd = "seek PlayingMp3 to 1:00";
        mciSendString(cmd,null,0,0);
```

this will play file from 1 minute. now i want to play file on speed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For winmm.dll :

```
mciSendString("set oursong speed " & 500, 0, 0, 0)
```

This should be helpful.

Try this :

WMP.settings.rate = 0.5

decrease the speed

look at the following link :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa969732.aspx

Comment: how can i get reference of WMP. i am using winmm.dll

Comment: I was suggesting to use Windows media player as it would be efficient to play sound but if you want it in winmm.dll then here is the code to decrease speed by 0.5 :     `code`   `mciSendString("set oursong speed " & 500, 0, 0, 0)`